# Using Google Feeds API to auto generate list of feeds in jquery mobile using "tap"

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, feed, tap

I'm having a problem generating a list of feed items (using Google Feeds API) triggered by a tap event on a list item. I can call the function on page load, and it works great. However, when I try to call the function on a "tap" event if generates a blank page.

Here is the list item I want to trigger the event on (on which I'm calling the 'tap' event):

```
<li id="welstech" class="listFeeds">
        <a href="#">
         <img src="_images/welstech-logo-db.jpg" alt="WELSTech" />       
         <h2>WELSTech Podcast</h2>
         <p>Discussions about Tech & Ministry</p>
        </a>
       </li>
```

Here is the script I have placed at the bottom of the html page:

```
    <script type="text/javascript>
    $(document).on('tap', '.listFeeds', function() {
    listAudioPosts("http://feeds.feedburner.com/welstech");
});
    </script>
```

Here is the function that it calls:

```
function listAudioPosts(feedurl){
    google.load("feeds", "1");
console.log("I'm still going 1");
    function initialize() {
console.log("I'm still going 2");
      var feed = new google.feeds.Feed(feedurl);
      feed.setNumEntries(10)
      var output = '<ul data-role="listview" data-split-icon="info">';
      var name = "welstech";
      feed.load(function(result) {
          if (!result.error) { 
              for (var i = 0; i < result.feed.entries.length; i++) {
                  var entry = result.feed.entries[i];
                  var mediaGroups = result.feed.entries[i].mediaGroups[0].contents[0];
                  var stripContentSnippet = entry.contentSnippet.replace(/[^a-zA-Z 0-9.:-]+/g,'');
                  var stripaContentSnippet = stripContentSnippet.replace('lt--pagingfilter--gt','');
                  output += '<li>';
                  output += '<a href="#">';
                  output += '<h2>' + entry.title + '</h2>';
                  output += '<p>' + stripaContentSnippet + '</p>';
                  output += '</a>';
                  output += '</li>';
                } // loop through all the feeds and create li elements
            } // end of if statement
            output += '</ul>';
            $("#testtouchoutput").html(output).trigger('refresh');
            $.mobile.changePage("#test");
        }); // end feed.load (function(result)
    } // end initialize function
    google.setOnLoadCallback(initialize);   
}
```

I know the function works, because I can call it on page load with this script at the bottom of my html page see below. I also know the function gets as far as the sub function initialize(), as I can see the console.log output before that sub function, but not the one after it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    listAudioPosts("http://feeds.feedburner.com/welstech");
</script>
```

So the second the home page loads, the function runs and the page refreshes to the list I want to generate...except I want to generate it on a "tap" event.

I'm a fairly new jquery programmer, so I'm sure it is something obvious. What am I missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't close the .on, try something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var timeTouched;
        $('.listFeeds').bind('touchstart', function() {
            timeTouched = new Date().getTime();
        }
        $('.listFeeds').bind('touchend', function() {
            if (new Date().getTime() - timeTouched < 200) { // Ended touch within 200 milliseconds, counts as a tap
                listAudioPosts("http://feeds.feedburner.com/welstech");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Make sure if your script is above wherever the .listFeeds element is defined, you include the $(document).ready() part, else it will be unable to bind the event to that element.

UPDATE: tap doesn't seem to be an event, updated with a potential solution.

UPDATE 2: Trying with .bind instead of .on.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. I do have the code correct. Also I tried wrapping in a $(document).ready(function), with the same results. Thanks for the suggestion however.

Comment: @MartinSpriggs don't think tap is an event, updated with a possible solution.

Comment: Tried the code. No luck. No event is fired. Not sure what you mean "don't think tap is an event". I know it works. I have a number of examples of it working. It is specific to jquery mobile I suppose. Thanks for trying to assist however.

Comment: I'll give one final solution a try, without .on, should work on default jQuery, updated my answer.

Comment: Tried bind as well, however I don't think the issue is in the event handler. I know the event is fired. It is somewhere in the function. In my testing, on tap the function is called and gets as far as the line right before function initialize. So in other words, I can see the results of a console.log just before the function initialize, but not the one after.